# Disable add to cart button on Woocommerce product category archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

How can I disable the "add to basket" button for products only on the "categories" page?

I still want it visible on the product page.

Many thanks

Comment: Not pretty, but you can use CSS to hide the "add to basket" div. Something like: .category #addtobasket {display:none;} you only have to look for the selectors. Wordpress uses a big css selector inside the body tag on each page so you can select pages, products, categories.

Answer (score 4):

The following will disable add to cart button on product category archive pages:

```
// Disable add to cart on product category archive pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_purchasable_on_product_category_archives', 10, 2 );
function disable_purchasable_on_product_category_archives( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if( is_product_category() )
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To target **specific product archive pages** you will replace use this instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_purchasable_on_product_category_archives', 10, 2 );
function disable_purchasable_on_product_category_archives( $purchasable, $product ) {
    // HERE define your product category terms
    $terms = array( 'shirts', 'games' ); 

    if( is_product_category( $terms ) )
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

See: [Woocommerce Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5)

Comment: Thank you for this filter. How would you call this filter on a category page?

Comment: @JohnSmith You don't need to call the filter, it works on itself. If you need to target specific product category archive pages, i have added an addition to my answer.

Comment: thanks very much for your update. I can see that it fires but for some reason the is_product_category() condition is never met even though it is on the categories page. Any ideas?